# How to upload image without using submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am doing image upload without using submit button. When user choose a image, he upload immediately. But I have a problem, Ajax only print "succes", but image is not in folder. PHP without ajax work.

**This is my html:**

```
<form action="../PHP/fotogaleria.php" method="post" class="form_fotogaleria" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="obal_fotogalerie">
        <div class="stvorcek">
            <label class="file_nahod">
                <input type="file" name="odoslat_fotogaleria" class="odid">
                <img class="priecinok" src="../Obrazky/folder.png">
                <p> Nahrať</p>
            </label>
        </div> <!-- koniec "stvorcek" -->
    </div> <!-- koniec "obal_fotogalerie" -->
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
$name = $_FILES['odoslat_fotogaleria']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['odoslat_fotogaleria']['tmp_name'];
$path = '../Obrazky-zvieratok/';
$cielovy_file = $path . basename($name);


move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$path.$name);
echo "success";
```

**And here is AJAX:**

```
$('.odid').change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
 url: '../PHP/fotogaleria.php',
 type: "POST",
 data: new FormData(this),
 contentType: false,
 cache: false,
 processData: false,
 success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
 }
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Does this function fine with a submit triggering the ajax?

Comment: look at your console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the input element to the `FormData` constructor. You should pass the form element instead.

```
data: new FormData($(this).closest('form').get(0)),
```